# Android: setting background of Button from variable

Tags: java, android

I'm coding a trivia app for android and it consists of questions and image options. Each question has 2 image options which are android buttons with different backgrounds set to them.

There are only two OnClickListeners, and I am currently changing the background like this:

```
button1.setBackground(R.drawable.image1)
```

I have over 30 different images I will be using as backgrounds for the buttons, and it seems inefficient to call the code above with the name of the image (image1.png in example) hardcoded.

I'd like to make it all work off a very effective function, like this:

```
nextQuestion(Question q)
{
display.setText("" + q.getQ()) ; // setting a new question to TextView called display
button1.setBackground(R.drawable.(q.getRandom())) ; //change background off of variable
button1.setBackground(R.drawable.(q.correctAnswerIndex)) ; // one is correct, one random
}
```

But I couldn't find a way to use variables with `setBackground()`
Is there any way I could do something like I wrote above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable",  getPackageName()); 
iV.setImageResource(resID);
```

set the resID to your 'q' value and use as required!

'icon' being the name of the drawable

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've gotten the first line of the code you suggested to work, but when I add the second line I get an error that reads: The method setBackground(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: This is what mines looks like 

`choiceOne.setBackgroundDrawable(resID) ;`

Comment: Sorry: iV.setImageResource(resID);